# Copy text from slide during presenting in Power Point?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, copy-paste

I have a presentation with some programming examples. I want to copy paste them into the tool right during a presentation for some demo. Unfortunately, if I click or drag mouse during presentation, it switches slides and selects nothing. This happens both on main screen and on secondaty one.

Is it possible to select and copy text during presentation somehow in PowerPoint?

Answer (score 1):

> > Is it possible to select and copy text during presentation somehow in PowerPoint?

Not from the slideshow view normally, but if you put the text in a text box control (inserted from the Developer tab) you could select/edit/copy/paste text there during a slide show.